# Js code for change class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this js first code is working while other code is not working ......why?
the css is given and the html code is given. After  first click first js code is working but after second click it is not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".i").click(function() {

    $(this).removeClass('i').addClass('j');
  });
  $(".j").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('j').addClass('i');
  });

});
```

```css
.j {
  background-color: blue;
}
.i {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox-plumber click1">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Installation</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selectBox-plumber click2">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Repair</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open1" class="box">
          <label for="one_1" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_1" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_1" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_1" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_1" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_1" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>

        <div id="open2" class="box">
          <label for="one_2" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_2" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_2" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_2" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_2" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_2" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to do `toggleClass`. How can it be work second time? it is only doing same thing on every click `removeClass('i').addClass('j');`

Comment: did you not see my second js code?

Comment: `.click` only binds on `DOM` so dynamically adding class doesn't work with `click` event.

Comment: Are you really using jq 1.3.0???

Comment: i am using jquery.min.js

Comment: @parthpahariya that's just a minified version...

Comment: @parthpahariya Sounds like you don't really know what you are doing, so replace `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js` with e.g: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` and then you can use posted answer (or better use relative protocol: `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"` )

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @A.Wolff its not ParthTrivedi :)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Oops, my bad! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on`, as you are toggling the classes on the elements it works with the dynamically modified elements.

```
$(function() {

  $("div.box").on("click", ".i, .j", function(evt) {

    // As there are nested elements in label. to hande 2 fired clicks.
    if (evt.target.tagName != 'INPUT')
    $(this).toggleClass("i j");

  });

});
```

And you need to update the version to jQuery 1.7 atleast.

```js
$(function() {

  $("div.box").on("click", ".i, .j", function(evt) {
    
    if (evt.target.tagName != 'INPUT')
    $(this).toggleClass("i j");

  });

});
```

```css
.j {
  background-color: blue;
}
.i {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox-plumber click1">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Installation</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selectBox-plumber click2">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Repair</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open1" class="box">
          <label for="one_1" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_1" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_1" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_1" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_1" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_1" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>

        <div id="open2" class="box">
          <label for="one_2" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_2" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_2" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_2" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_2" class="i">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_2" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP jquery version 1.3.0 doesn't support `on()` method

Comment: @parthpahariya What is only working one time? Have you upgraded your jQuery version? If ya, it will work, if not it won't work, not even one time. So which exact code are you using with which jq version? You have to seriously consider to improve your 'futur' comments in order to get accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

When your page is built all 'i' class elements get: `$(this).removeClass('i').addClass('j');` click handler, while all 'j' class elements get: `$(this).removeClass('j').addClass('i');`.

This is not changed even when an element class is changed.

You can use: `.toggleClass("i j")`

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".i", function() {

        $(this).removeClass('i').addClass('j');
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".j", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('j').addClass('i');
    });

});
```

For Jquery vesion before 1.7, try this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".i").live("click", function() {

    $(this).removeClass('i').addClass('j');
  });
  $(".j").live("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('j').addClass('i');
  });

});
```

**About toggleClass**: 
toggleClass really implemented like this:

```
            ...
            while ( (className = classNames[ i++ ]) ) {
                // check each className given, space separated list
                if ( self.hasClass( className ) ) {
                    self.removeClass( className );
                } else {
                    self.addClass( className );
                }
            }
            ...
```

So .removeClass('i').addClass('j') like you do is really get better performance.

Comment: @Hitmands But regarding expected OP's behaviour, delegation is accurate

Comment: What's mean  OP's behaviour?
 By the way, you need to delegate when you cannot attach a listener directly, but, this is not the case...
He needs just to toggle classes already appendend.

Comment: @Hitmands OP for opening poster. And ya, delegation isn't required BUT makes code more readable imho

Comment: I disagree, totally. Why "listen **a** and do something if is **b**" should be more readable than "listen **b** and do something" ?

Comment: @Hitmands Suppose you want to check for any event bound to `.j` elements *just checking code* (not using any debug tool listing event listener). The delegated version would be obvious, the none delegated one would be less. But that's still my opinion, yours is for sure valid. That's said, i wouldn't use the code as posted in this answer but simply: `$(staticContainer).on("click", ".i, .j", handler);`

Comment: @Hitmands Thank, you are right. I tried to follow what he was trying to do. It's just a simple working solution. I got good learning from your feedback.